# How to find the column number for a specific value and the CSV file at that location

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to split a csv file at a specific row with a specific value, but i cannot figure out how to do it.
The csv file is a data export from a program we use and it consist of two different parts. The file looks like this and the second part is always started with '[Faces]'.

```
[Name]
Plane 1750

[Data]
Node Number, X [ m ], Y [ m ], Z [ m ], AV WF
0, -1.96213058e+02, -2.73303375e+02, 1.75000000e+00, 2.01742917e-01
1, -1.96173523e+02, -2.73252655e+02, 1.75000000e+00, 2.02091664e-01
606479, -2.06638428e+02, 2.93843475e+02, 1.75000000e+00, 3.21377516e-01
606480, -2.05079956e+02, 2.94933014e+02, 1.75000000e+00, 3.27591240e-01

[Faces]
400, 335, 336, 339, 338
196775, 644, 610, 611, 196774
1658, 1657, 1656, 196787, 196788
1562, 1561, 1439, 1438, 196794
```

Now I would like to know how I could split the file at the location of the value '[Faces]' and save all the data below that in a new csv file.

This execution is part of a script which already uses pandas and numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to consume lines until we meet `[Faces]` line:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    while fp.readline().strip() != '[Faces]':
        pass
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, skipinitialspace=True)

with open('faces.csv') as fp:
    fp.write('[Faces]\n')
    df.to_csv(fp, index=False)
```

Content of `faces.csv`:

```
[Faces]
0,1,2,3,4
400,335,336,339,338
196775,644,610,611,196774
1658,1657,1656,196787,196788
1562,1561,1439,1438,196794
```

**Update**

Without Pandas:

```
with open('data.txt') as inp, open('faces.csv', 'w') as out:
    while inp.readline().strip() != '[Faces]':
        pass
    out.writelines(['Faces\n'] + inp.readlines())
```

**Update 2**

```
import shutil

with open('data.txt', 'r') as inp, \
     open('faces.csv', 'w') as out, \
     open('temp.txt', 'w') as tmp:
    fp = tmp
    for line in inp:
        if line == '[Faces]\n':
            fp = out
        fp.write(line)

shutil.move('temp.txt', 'data2.txt')
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This helps but is it also possible to include the row with [faces] and delete the [faces] information from the old file? and because a dataframe was used, the column numbers are also included in the file. How can those be deleted from the file?

Comment: @Pieter725. I updated my answer. It's possible to do it without pandas if you prefer.

Comment: when i excecuted the code it could nog write the file, the writing function should be added to the open function. If you could show the method without pandas that would be great.

Comment: Is it also possible to delete al the data below '[Faces]' in original file?